# Delays when using Firefox (34.0) to query neo4j on an remote machine

Tags: firefox, neo4j

I have a strange problem with Firefox (34.0) vs. Internet Explorer (11) and Neo4j (community 2.1.6):

When I connect locally (localhost:7474/browser), I get answers in <= 200ms time with both browsers.

When I connect to a remote computer (other:7474/browser), the answers in Firefox take 30 seconds plus a few milliseconds.

Has anyone the same problem or any ideas for the reason of these delays?

Comment: Are you sure not to have any proxies configured?

Comment: We have a proxy for, but not for the internal company domain. And the proxy configuration is the same for IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem myself. In Internet Option -> Connections -> LAN settings, there is a proxy configured and "Bypass Proxy Server for local addresses" enabled. Firefox is configured to use System Proxy Settings.

In IE, both `hostname` and `hostname.mydomain.com` works. In Firefox, only `hostname.mydomain.com` works. If I use only hostname, the delay occurs (I still don't understand why). If I switch to manually proxy configuration in Firefox and explicitely add `hostname` to the exclusion list, it works without the delay.

So it has to do with the Proxy Settings, although I would expect that the local domain would be appended to `hostname`, if not fully qualified, and the result should be the same. So this seems to be a bug in Firefox?! But it does not occur when connecting to e.g. an Apache server. So it is a probably a problem in the Neo4j browser code.